# need to substring out numeric data from a character field in SAS

Tags: sas, character, substring, wildcard

I have a data set with 2 variables: a subject id number and a result.  The result is a character variable.  It was read in from an excel spreadsheet.  Most results are numbers, but some of the results have a letter after them which was serving as a footnote in the excel file.  I need to get rid of the letters after the numbers so I can convert the data to numeric for analysis.  How can I do this? Below is some code to create an example dataset of the structure that I'm talking about.

```
data test;
input id result $ ;
datalines;
1 13 
2 15 
3 20 
4 25c 
5 75 
6 99c 
7 89b 
8 10a 
9 100 
10 67
;
run;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [`compress`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000212246.htm) and [`input`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000180357.htm) functions.

```
num = input(compress(result, , "dk"), best.);
```

`input` converts character to numeric, interpreting the data using the informat you provide (`best.` here).

`compress` can be used to strip certain characters from a string, here it is used with the `d` modifier to request that all numeric digits be excluded, and the `k` modifier to request that the selected characters be kept rather than removed.

You may have to tweak the `compress` arguments a bit to deal with more complicated cases such as decimal points.

Comment: Can you explain how the code would differ with decimal points?  My data does have decimal points and the code above strips them out.

Comment: Take a look at the second argument of the [`compress(<source><, chars><, modifiers>)` function](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000212246.htm). This is where you specify your list of characters to be removed (or kept with the `k` modifier). You can put a string here containing any additional characters you want to preserve. e.g. `(var, "-£,.", "dk")` (or its equivalent `(var, "-£,.0123456789", "k")`) would keep only digits, the minus and pound signs, commas and points.